# Eclipse binding key not working fo TFS

Tags: eclipse, tfs, macros, eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse Neon and I'm using TFS (Team foundation server) plugin.

I 'm trying to bind keys to operation of category Team foundation server, but none of it works.

I can do the operation manually but not using the keys I define.

Other keys binding are working fine.

Comment: Which key do you set for the TFS Plugin? make sure there are no duplicated keys set for the items. Could you please capture the screenshot for reference here?

Comment: There's no duplicated keys, for example I set Compare to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Z in Windows Category Team Foundation Server User column marked as U

Comment: hello? bounty anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this at my side and can reproduce your issue. Set keys for other items worked correctly.

I help you submit a [feedback here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/53458/eclipse-tfs-bind-key-not-working.html), please track it as needed.

Comment: I got an answer that nothing will be fixed/changed from TFS: "...we cannot investigate the issue ..."